# Sending __string to __unsafe_unretained changes retain/release properties of pointer

Tags: objective-c, xcode, automatic-ref-counting, clang

Following is a code segment which I learnt in a lynda iOS training course based on iOS 4 (without ARC).

I was going to implement the same code in my Xcode 4.2 which has ARC turned on with the iOS 5 SDK. It gave me this error:

> error: Semantic Issue: Sending '__strong id *' to parameter of type '__unsafe_unretained id **' changes retain/release properties of pointer"

```
- (NSNumber *) insertRow:(NSDictionary *) record {
    // NSLog(@"%s", __FUNCTION__);
    int dictSize = [record count];

    // the values array is used as the argument list for bindSQL
    id keys[dictSize];  // not used, just a side-effect of getObjects:andKeys
    id values[dictSize];
    [record getObjects:values andKeys:keys];    // convenient for the C array

    // construct the query
    NSMutableArray * placeHoldersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:dictSize];
    for (int i = 0; i < dictSize; i++)  // array of ? markers for placeholders in query
        [placeHoldersArray addObject: [NSString stringWithString:@"?"]];

    NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (%@) values (%@)",
                        tableName,
                        [[record allKeys] componentsJoinedByString:@","],
                        [placeHoldersArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]];

    [self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] arguments:(va_list)values];
    sqlite3_step(statement);
    if(sqlite3_finalize(statement) == SQLITE_OK) {
        return [self lastInsertId];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"doQuery: sqlite3_finalize failed (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    }
}
```

** The real case came with the following segment of this whole function.**

```
int dictSize = [record count];

// the values array is used as the argument list for bindSQL
id keys[dictSize];  // not used, just a side-effect of getObjects:andKeys
id values[dictSize];
[record getObjects:values andKeys:keys];    // convenient for the C array
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: 1. Which line, precisely, is giving you that compiler warning/error; 2. You're using C style subscripts with `keys` and `values`, which is pretty unusual in iOS apps. Generally in Objective-C we'd use a `NSMutableArray`, which offers richer functionality and checks for things like the bounds of the array, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot wrong with that function.  The fix for your compiler error is simply to declare `keys` and `values` with the `__unsafe_unretained` ownership qualifier:

```
__unsafe_unretained id keys[dictSize];  // not used, just a side-effect of getObjects:andKeys
__unsafe_unretained id values[dictSize];
```

However, the cast `(va_list)values` is undefined behavior.  Don't do it.

Since you're not using the `keys` array at all, it would be better to do something like this:

```
- (NSNumber *) insertRow:(NSDictionary *) record {
    int count = [record count];

    NSMutableArray * placeHoldersArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        [placeHoldersArray addObject: @"?"];
    }

    NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (%@) values (%@)",
                        tableName,
                        [[record allKeys] componentsJoinedByString:@","],
                        [placeHoldersArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]];

    [self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] arguments:[record allValues]];
    sqlite3_step(statement);
    if(sqlite3_finalize(statement) == SQLITE_OK) {
        return [self lastInsertId];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"doQuery: sqlite3_finalize failed (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    }
}
```

And then modify `bindSQL:arguments:` to take an `NSArray *` instead of a `va_list`.  If you need help doing that, show us the source code of `bindSQL:arguments:`.

(However, I don't think it's documented that `allKeys` and `allValues` return parallel arrays…)

Answer (score 0):

Edited for const char pointer:

```
- (NSNumber *) insertRow:(NSDictionary *) record {
    NSArray * placeHoldersArray = [NSArray array];
    const char * cStrings[record.count];
    NSArray * keys = [record allKeys];
    NSUInteger i=0;
    for (id key in keys) {
        id object = [record objectForKey:key];
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[NSString class]])
            cStrings[i++] = [(NSString*)object UTF8String];
        else
            @throw [NSException exceptionWithName:NSInvalidArgumentException reason:@"Expected NSString" userInfo:nil];
        placeHoldersArray = [placeHoldersArray arrayByAddingObject: @"?"]; 
    }    
    NSString * query = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"insert into %@ (%@) values (%@)",
                            tableName,
                            [keys componentsJoinedByString:@","],
                            [placeHoldersArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]];

    [self bindSQL:[query UTF8String] arguments:(va_list)cStrings];
    sqlite3_step(statement);
    if(sqlite3_finalize(statement) == SQLITE_OK) {
        return [self lastInsertId];
    } else {
        NSLog(@"doQuery: sqlite3_finalize failed (%s)", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        return [NSNumber numberWithInt:0];
    }
}
```

In the update method, you should understand that a va_list is just a group of any number of arguments.  It is assumed that the method that is called knows how to determine the type.  An example of this is with NSLog.  It uses the format string to determine the type of an unknown number of variables, which are passed in as a va_list, i.e. comma separated values.  Because you only have one value, just pass in the value.  I am sketchy on whether sqlite wants a c string or if it will take an integer in this case.

Comment: You use a `values` variable but you haven't defined it.